# I can't receive push notifications in app from Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I configured Parse API in my app and everything works except push notifications. I tried to send them from the site but they don't arrive in app.
I did everything as written in [documentation](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications), but I'm not able to receive notification pushes.

I was able to receive one and when I pressed it app crashed. Now I tried to change something but even with reversing I cannot receive them anymore. How can I resolve my problem?

EDIT: Since some users may be interested, here's the parts of the code I used for push notifications:

Main Class (not MainActivity though):

```
    public class InstantsApplication extends Application {
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Hidden
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");



    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");

            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

AndroidManifest (permissions not here included, trust me I have put them):

```
<!-- PARSE -->
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
          android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <!--
          IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name.
        -->
        <!-- I have hidden package name root for this question -->
        <category android:name="com.xxxxxxxx.instants" />


    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met this problem before, that because you use the newest Parse api.
There are just a few changes you need to make.

First, to fix the error directly caused by issuing the push from the Parse backend you need to declare a notification icon for the Parse push in your Manifest.

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

use before the closing application-Tag.

Issuing another push from the backend now will give you a push notification as you expect. So far so good. Clicking the push will result in an app crash again. To fix this you need to remove the now deprecated call `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(...)` and add your own Receiver class. I did this in the *.util package just as the following:

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Next, change the default Parse receiver to the one just created: - Go to your Manifest file.

```
 <receiver
            android:name="your.package.name.utils.Receiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Helpful, but you told me all things I already tried and reversed. Still I don't receive push notifications (anyway I already set the icon but didn't mention here)

Comment: What show on your log-cat? I really tried this, and it will show D/com.parse.push﹕ successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.

Comment: Me too, but still I don't receive notifications

Comment: I actually uninstalled and ran the app again and now works.. I don't know why this works sometimes. Thanks for help and confirms to my doubts about receiver

Comment: What device are you using? Have you tried on emulator?

Comment: Anyway I'm using only emulator. Oh, and above all app doesn't crash anymore

Comment: @bjiang  i m using this code to send notification from an android device to another http://pastie.org/10223872  but i m not recieving any notification i also have made parseReciver extends BroadCastReciever

Comment: @Erum you may open a question and post your code there.

Comment: @bjiang  i am blocked to ask question can u pls come here so that i can share what is the issue in code http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78662/fancycoverflow  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/androidians