# Cannot receive push notification from parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented what parse.com had in their tutorial and when I send a push from parse dashboard it says Succeeded but the number of pushes sent is 0. However whenever I want to send the push it says recepient 1 which means it recognizes my device. I did what it says in this link but it doesnt work:
[I can't receive push notifications in app from Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367362/i-cant-receive-push-notifications-in-app-from-parse)
I'm very confused why I'm not receiving any notification here is my Application class code:

```
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

here is my manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="com.myapp.main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

and here is the rest of manifest related to parse push:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.myapp.main" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- replace @drawable/push_icon with your push icon identifier -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/applogo"/>
```

EDIT: Here is the log:

```
02-25 13:52:53.681    4636-4653/com.myapp.main E/com.parse.ManifestInfo﹕ Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="com.myapp.main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.myapp.main" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

02-25 13:57:13.004    5598-5598/com.myapp.main E/com.parse.PushService﹕ Tried to use push, but this app is not configured for push due to: Push is not configured for this app because the app manifest is missing required declarations. Please add the following declarations to your app manifest to support either GCM or PPNS for push (or both). To enable GCM support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.myapp.main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.main.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.myapp.main" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
To enable PPNS support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
02-25 14:12:25.534  10046-10046/com.myapp.main E/com.parse.push﹕ successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.
```

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my manifest to this:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.vitrin.main" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I still get that error + :

```
02-25 15:44:33.042  32710-32710/com.myapp.main E/com.parse.PushService﹕      PushService somehow started even though this device doesn't support push.
02-25 15:44:33.042  32710-32710/com.myapp.main E/com.parse.PushService﹕ Started push service even though no push service is enabled: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.myapp.main cmp=com.myapp.main/com.parse.PushService (has extras) }
02-25 15:45:10.508  32710-32710/com.myapp.main E/com.parse.PushService﹕ Started push service even though no push service is enabled: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.myapp.main cmp=com.myapp.main/com.parse.PushService (has extras) }
```

but for some reason it is working!!

Answer (score 0):

`android:name="com.myapp.main.permission.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"`

Can you change it to have only one "permission" in the name?