# Parse GCM push notifications not working on Android 6.0 Marshmallow Developer Preview 3

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have registered the necessary permissions, services, and broadcast receivers in my `AndroidManifest.xml` and I have Parse push notifications working on pre Android M devices. I am getting an error (posted below) in the Android 6.0 Marshmallow Developer Preview 3 running on my Nexus 5. The user is successfully registering and I can view it in the Parse dashboard on Parse.com, but the `pushType` and `deviceLastTokenModified` are `undefined`. I can't help but think this is an issue with the Parse SDK considering this is working fine on Pre Android M devices. It could be an issue with Android M's permission changes, except none of the permissions I am requesting fall under the category that ask the user to grant it.

Here is the error::

```
08-30 19:29:19.671  11848-11848/com.example.app V/com.parse.ManifestInfo﹕ Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.richardlucasapps.eaglescribe.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.richardlucasapps.eaglescribe.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.richardlucasapps.eaglescribe" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
08-30 19:29:19.671  11848-11848/com.example.app V/com.parse.ManifestInfo﹕ Using none for push.
```

Here is how I am initializing Parse and setting it up for push notifications:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
        Parse.initialize(this, applicationId, clientId);

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().increment("RunCount");
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();

        ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        parseInstallation.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        parseInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }
}
```

Here is a condensed version of my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.app” >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".global.MyApplication">
    <!-- For Parse Notification Push Service -->
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.app” />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Take look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27367613/4186942) may help you. Some permission need to prompt . For more details, plz refer [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#coding).

Comment: @bjiang all the permissions I am requesting to enable Parse push notifications are `PROTECTION_NORMAL`, which do not require a user prompt. I have thoroughly checked and I have everything in the manifest that is outlined here: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing

Comment: Is this specific to Marshmallow? If so, opening an issue on the Parse Android SDK repository would be helpful: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues

Comment: @HectorRamos thank you for the recommendation. I have filed the issue here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/101
I will update this thread when I figure this out, I promise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Parse library you are using in your project. I was using 1.9.4 and updated to Parse 1.10.1 and now my Android Marshmallow device is successfully registering for and receiving push notifications.

[Grab the most up to date Parse library here.](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing)